# Voxel River Generation at Biome Borders or Biome Blending

Tags: procedural-generation, voxels

I'm creating a voxel (block, Minecraft like) game and I have different biomes (flatland, mountains, ect) and the problem is they are abrupt changes when biomes end /begin. I'm using 3d perlin noise, so I can't just "average out" the heights. So I thought to make rivers when biomes end /begin. Does anyone know how I could do this, or how it could work? With 3d noise I get very nice features, however the noise represents density rather than height, so I'm not sure how to go about doing "weight" and such. If not, how can I do blending with 3d perlin noise? Many thanks in advance. I'm also wondering of how  Currently, for each chunk of the world I have a certain chunkGen set, and when the biome changes (randomly determined) the chunkGen changes. Even if I were to generate on a block by block basis, I'm not exactly too sure how that could help me as the 3d perlin value I'm getting is of density. I think my best bet would be using 2d perlin with 3d perlin, the 2d for height and the 3d for ridges but I have no idea of how to implement this.  Would it also be possible to create a buffer terrain between the biomes? with the averages of the octaves, gain, frequency? EDIT: I've actually just tried buffer terrain but it doesn't work well, often enough it moves up randomly or happens in the middle of lakes.

Comment: Presumably you tried interpolating the density fields before thresholding?

Comment: No, I havent... I'm not too sure about linear interpolation and such, how would I go about that? What would I interpolate, and how would that work?

Comment: If one biome says this voxel should have a density of 0.1 and the other biome says it should have a density of 2.3, and the voxel is halfway between the two, then it should have a density of 1.2 (just the average of the two density values)

Comment: Biomes are generated by the chunk, so it will never be that one biome is saying this and the other is saying that... How would I generate by the block?

Comment: My entire world is generated by the chunk... Basically I have a chunk generator that I assign to the world, so when a new biome comes I just change the generator

Comment: You must evaluate more than one biome at a site if you want to blend them without abrupt transitions at the chunk borders. One chunk must be able to straddle two biomes.

Comment: That will be difficult to implement, but I will give it a try and come back to here.

Comment: I have no idea how to implement biomes by a block-basis, do you have any tutorials or point me in the direction to do such thing?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to edit your question to ask that then (after searching here for past Q&A on assigning and blending biomes)

Comment: Please ask one question per post. If you want to ask something new, remake your question as a whole to ask that in detail - don't just tack a new question onto the end.

Comment: My apologies, I've added more detail.